# Nodejs Crypto RSA_NO_PADDING equivalent in Python?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, rsa

I'm integrating an API using nodejs Crypto RSA.
The problem is they're using crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING which I can't decrypt in python.
I've tried pycrypto, cryptography, pycryptodome but still no hope.
Here is the nodejs encrypt fucntion. Please give me some hope :(.

```js
const encryptWithPubKey = (buffer, keyPath, rsaPadding = crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING) => {
  const pubKey = fs.readFileSync(keyPath)
  const encrypter = { key: pubKey, padding: rsaPadding }
  const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(encrypter, buffer).toString('base64')
  return encrypted
};
```

Comment: RSA without padding (textbook RSA) is insecure. For this reason many libraries don't support it at all. The outdated _PyCrypto_ still allows this with [`RSA.construct`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html). However, the use of [textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20087) _in practice_ can only be strongly discouraged for security reasons. The successor _PyCryptodome_ already generates an exception: `NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead`.

Comment: Thanks @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk. I will remove the comment.